# hwclock is wrong Linux

Tags: linux

I'm on an Arch Linux USB. My hardware clock is in PDT but hwclock is interpreting it as UTC. I tried starting ntp with `ntpd -u ntp:ntp` but it doesn't start. Changing the timezone reverted the clock by 7 hours so that didn't work.

How do I set my clocks to the correct time?

It's important because I'm trying to run some  code that depends on the OS's clock.

Answer (score 1):

This command corrected the system time `timedatectl set-ntp true`

And this command sets the hardware clock to the system time `hwclock --systohc`

Now I'm curious if the Windows on this machine will misinterpret the hardware clock as PDT, now that it's set to UTC.